# How to keep reference to another jQuery object in a jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a simple `jQuery` plugin for my purpose, which:

1. creates a background `div` (for blocking purposes, like a `modal dialog`). (referenced with `backDiv`)
2. shows that background.
3. shows `$(this)`.
4. removes background and hides `$(this)` when background clicked.

I am able to do all of these except 4th one: As I can't save a reference to the background `div`, I cannot get it back and remove it.

I tried `$(this).data('backDiv',backDiv);` and `$(this)[0].backDiv = backDiv;`

I know that there are various plugins that does this including the jQuery's own dialog function, but I want to create my own version.

I cannot keep this variable globally, so, how can I keep a reference to `backDiv` in a jQuery object, (or DOM object?) if that's even possible at all?

**update:** I allow multiple of these elements show on top of each other: `Nested modal dialogs`.

**update-2**:

```js
(function($) {

  $.fn.showModal = function() {
    var backDiv = $('<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: rgba(55, 55, 55, 0.5); position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;">This is backDiv</div>');
    $(this).data('backDiv', backDiv);
    $('body').append(backDiv);

    //TODO: bringToFront(backDiv);
    $(this).show();
    //TODO: bringToFront($(this);

    var thisRef = $(this);
    backDiv.click(function() {
      thisRef.closeModal();
    });

    return $(this);
  };
  $.fn.closeModal = function() {
    //PROBLEM (null): var backDiv = $(this).data('backDiv');
    //backDiv.remove();
    $(this).data('backDiv', '');
    $(this).hide();
  }
}(jQuery));

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#a').showModal();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a" style="display:none;z-Index:2;background:red; width: 100px; height:50px;position:absolute"></div>
```

Comment: Using `class/id selector`  ?

Comment: Share your plugin code - `$(this).data('backDiv',backDiv);` should work, then `var backDiv = $(this).data('backDiv');`

Comment: can you please make a fiddle for better understanding??

Comment: Rayon Dabre's answer is the simplest I believe.. else the reference can also be stored in a variable for later use,

Comment: I added the code here, `$(this).data('backDiv')` returns null

Comment: I can't use class as there may be nested usage. I can use id by generating a unique index which is incremented by 1 and can set that id to 'data' property. But I want to use that as the last resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `data-backDiv=""` into you dynamic modal div

Change below

```
var backDiv = $('<div data-backDiv="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: rgba(55, 55, 55, 0.5); position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;">This is backDiv</div>');
```

Comment: As this is the direct solution to my problem I selected this answer. So, it seems like the variable for data must already exist for dynamic divs. If not, please share your experience.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to work in terms of **complex dom objects**, something similar *angular directives*, basically, you have to work with components that are represented in the dom as Group of Objects.

So, following what I'm saying, your modal component should be something like that:

```js
var Modal = (function($) {
  var tpl = '<div style="display:none;" class="modal"><div class="modal-backdrop"></div><div class="modal-content"></div></div>';
  
  function Modal(container) {
    var self = this;

    this.container = $(container || 'body');
    this.tpl = $(tpl).appendTo(this.container);
    this.content = $('.modal-content', this.tpl);
    this.backdrop = $('.modal-backdrop', this.tpl);
    
    this.isOpened = false;
    
    this.ANIMATION_DURATION = 500;
    
    this.backdrop.click(function(e) { self.toggle(e) });
  }
  
  Modal.prototype.show = function(cb) {
    var self = this;
    cb = $.isFunction(cb) ? cb : $.noop;
  
    this.tpl.fadeIn(this.ANIMATION_DURATION, function() {
      self.isOpened = true;
      cb();
    });
    
    return this;
  };
  
  Modal.prototype.hide = function(cb) {
    var self = this;
    cb = $.isFunction(cb) ? cb : $.noop;
  
    this.tpl.fadeOut(this.ANIMATION_DURATION, function() {
      self.isOpened = false;
      cb();
    });
    
    return this;
  };
  
  Modal.prototype.toggle = function() {
    if(this.isOpened) {
      return this.hide();
    }
    
    return this.show();
  };
  
  Modal.prototype.setContent = function(content) {
    this.content.html($('<div />').append(content).html());
    
    return this;
  };
  
  
  return Modal;
})(window.jQuery);

function ExampleCtrl($) {
  var modal = new Modal();
  
  modal.setContent('<h1>Hello World</h1>');
  
  $('#test').click(function() {
    modal.show();
  });
}

window.jQuery(document).ready(ExampleCtrl);
```

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.modal .modal-backdrop {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}

.modal .modal-content {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  position: absolute;
  
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -150px;
  margin-top: -75px;
  
  line-height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="test">Test Modal</button>
```

Comment: This is a very very valuable post and it gave me new ideas, thank you very much! I didn't select this just because it is not a "direct" solution to my problem.

Comment: There's no problem, generally, what I prefer is doing things in as better way as possible :)

Comment: I am agree with you that this total solution seems cleaner and more scalable.

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrive data attribute value using JQuery use following code

### Syntax

```
$('selector').data('data-KeyName');
```

### Example

```
1. $(this).data('backDiv'); // use to retrive value    or
2. var temp=$(this).data('backDiv'); // use to retrive value and assign into variable
```

Comment: I added the code, unfortunately `$(this).data('backDiv')` returns null

Comment: Please make sure data must be assign before access the same. otherwise it's return null